# Redirecting to a razor page after successful login in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, redirect, http-redirect

I want to redirect to the following Razor page after successful login:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private readonly AppContext _context;

    public AdminController(AppContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost("adminLogin")]
    public IActionResult Login(LoginInfo login)
    {
        Admin adminInDb = _context.Admins.FirstOrDefault(admin => admin.Username == login.Username);

        if (adminInDb == null && HashGenerator.VerifyHash(adminInDb.Password, login.Password, adminInDb.Salt))
        {
            //return RedirectToPage("/pages/login.html");
            return Ok(CreateToken(adminInDb.Id, adminInDb.Username));
        }

        return Unauthorized();
    }

    /*
    [HttpPost("adminLogin")]
    public IActionResult Login(LoginInfo login)
    {
        Admin adminInDb = _context.Admins.FirstOrDefault(admin => admin.Username == login.Username);

        if (adminInDb != null && HashGenerator.VerifyHash(adminInDb.Password, login.Password, adminInDb.Salt))
        {
            return RedirectToPage("/admin");
            //return Ok(CreateToken(adminInDb.Id, adminInDb.Username));
        }

        return Unauthorized();
    }
    */

    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var users = _context.Users.ToList();
        return View(users);
    }

    private UserToken CreateToken(long userId, string username)
    {
        var expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(5);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, $"{userId}"),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, username),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            }),
            Expires = expires,
            Issuer = JwtConfiguration.ValidIssuer,
            Audience = JwtConfiguration.ValidAudience,
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
                new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JwtConfiguration.IssuerSigningKey)),
                    SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var jwtToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

        return new UserToken { Username = username, ExpiresAt = expires, JWT = jwtToken };
    }
}
```

My Razor `page.cshtml`:

```
@page "/admin"
@{
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <!-- Fügen Sie weitere Spalten hinzu, je nach Ihren Anforderungen -->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var user in Model.Users)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@user.Id</td>
                    <td>@user.Username</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

I don't know if I have to do something in the `page.cshtml.cs` but it looks kinda OK. I just want to redirect the user to the Razor page after login which is NOT in `wwwroot`.

Maybe I have to add something to the `program.cs` but I have no idea.

I have been literally working on this basic page for 15 hours and I couldn't find any solution. It has been a long time since I worked with C# the last time, maybe a framework changed I don't know.....

Comment: A controller-based web API consists of one or more controller classes that derive from `ControllerBase`.  If your controller is api controller, you can have a look at [ControllerBase class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#controllerbase-class) .

Comment: You've decorated your controller with `[ApiController]` - so this is now an **API** that can return data - but it cannot support the **views** and redirecting to a new page. For that, you need a regular **MVC** controller (not an "API controller")

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to redirect the user to the razor page after login

make sure add the below route code in the program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
...
app.MapRazorPages();
```

then try:

```
return Redirect("https://localhost:7090/Pagename");//use your port
```

You can set a breakpoint at razor page.cshtml.cs to see whether it excute the mothod.

Comment: Hi @Jugobetrugo, any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know?